# Video.js remove HTML spans

Tags: javascript, video.js

When I prerender video.js player then it add a lot of `<span>`s in html like:

```html
<span class="vjs-control-text">Video Player is loading.</span>
    </div><button class="vjs-big-play-button" type="button" title="Play Video" aria-disabled="false" style="display: block;">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span>
    <span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">Play Video</span>
```

Some of that spans have content like "Video player is loading." or "Play Video".

My page is in other language than english and because of SEO (I don't want google to see english content at the top of html document) I need to remove all that spans. I also don't even display play/stop buttons so I don't need it in html.

**How to remove this spans?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the spans you have to remove every span with the class

> vjs-control-text

```
function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
removeElementsByClass('vjs-control-text');
```

Comment: Should not need to use `!important` if you override the style using the correct selector hierarchy.

Comment: I don't want to hide it, it's already hidden I don't use it and I want to totally remove it. For Google it doesn't matter if it's shown or not.

Comment: This is a very convoluted and "hacky" approach to something which can be achieved with configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

**Video.js** comes with it's own set of language files [which you can find here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/tree/master/lang). Documentation on using languages [can be found here](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-languages.html).

If you want to remove them, even if you can use your local language with it, you can find more options for configuring the player [here](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-options.html#standard-video-element-options).

I haven't read over all of the options but there are a lot of them and the ability to remove the video controls is in there too.

Comment: Which option is for disabling this control-texts? I'm looking for it but can't find.

Comment: No, I already had control to false before even writing this post. I wrote in post: `I also don't even display play/stop buttons so I don't need it in html.`. Spans `.cjs-control-text` still stay in HTML. I don't really see an option to remove spans within configuration.